# Recommend a package to support tag input?

Tags: angular

I'm hoping this is as easy as just pointing me to a package I can install with npm.

Looking to add a component to my app that has has simple tag functionality (similar to the Tags input here on so)

See: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Can someone point me in the direction of something like that for Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install

```
npm install angular2-tag-input --save
```

For more detail visit - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tag-input

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  It seems to depend on a newer version of angular2 than we're using and I couldn't find either a combination of versions that seemed to play nicely.

I can try to see if an older version works...

Comment: I did end up using this.. I just had to use an older version ("angular2-tag-input": "1.1.0")